# Finder Sidebar in macOS Big Sur doesn't persist width change

Tags: macos, finder, big-sur

I want to make the sidebar in Finder in macOS Big Sur 11.2.1 wider, but every time I restart Finder the sidebar goes back to its original smaller width. Is there any way to make the width change persist?

[image: finder image save sidebar]

Comment: Does "restarting Finder" means Force Quit the app or open a new window when no other is opened ?

Comment: actually you're right. Finder does remember the sidebar width. What instead doesn't remember is that finder window that opens when trying to save a file. I wish I could attach a screenshot here.

Comment: You can edit your question by adding the screenshot ;)

Comment: @tama nice! Learning something new every day!